# fixed window size for chrome web app

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Chrome web app (hosted app) and I need to make the window not resizable.

This is my current `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Web app",
  "description": "Description.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "*://localhost/view/main"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://localhost/view/main",
      "container": "panel",
      "height": 645,
      "width": 800
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "favicon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I can set the initial size but I can't find a way to make it fixed. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the maxHeight,maxWidth and minHeight and minWidth properties to the "launch" object.so you can fixed your window size for chrome web app and make it no resizable.
For example,

```
   launch: {
      "web_url": "http://localhost/view/main",
      "container": "panel",
      "height": 645,
      "width": 800,
      "minHeight":645,
      "minWidth":800,
      "maxHeight":645,
      "maxWidth":800      
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Using chrome v47 and tested with a webapp launched in panel mode.